# How to Get SQL data that contains given data as a part

Tags: c#, sql, mdf

I need to Display inventory Report that have Fields like BillDate, ProductName,Qty.

And I Need Only that product With BillDate Contains Selected Month.

If I Selected Month As Jan Only of Jan Month Bills should Be displayed.

Comment: Use a date range : date >= jan 1 && date < jan 31  or use between

Comment: I Am selecting Month through Combo Box

Comment: Please edit your question to be clear, if you have problems with the SQL or with the C# Code. Please also add the things you tried.

Comment: You still need to create a range of dates from the 1st of the month to the last day of the month.

Answer (score 2):

The normal approach would be a simple SQL query with a `WHERE` clause, like this:

```
select dir.*
from display_inventory_report dir
where dir.bill_date >= '2019-01-01' and
      dir.bill_date < '2019-02-01';
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the simple example in SQL below should help you:

```
 select BillDate, ProductName,Qty
from YourTable
WHERE BillDate BETWEEN  '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-31'
```